# User clicks during a GridView.DataBind call causes ArgumentException

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

I have read a lot about the popular **Invalid postback or callback argument** error message.

I get this error if I rush the web page by clicking on any type of link/redirect (in this case an ASP LinkButton, but the same result occurs when using an ASP Button) before a web page GridView has finished data binding.

The data being bound is very large and, ideally, I should add paging to make it execute faster. However, besides the click, there is no additional data being modified, including any client scripts, so I am unsure why this error is occurring.

Full error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I don't want to disable event validation for security reasons and I know that the large DataBind operation is the reason for this but I don't know why.

I have also tried disabling the grid validation as a simple test but this did not solve the issue:

```
myGrid.ValidateRequestMode = ValidateRequestMode.Disabled
```

The LinkButton is **not** using `PostBackUrl` and is instead using a Click event + `Response.Redirect` (I removed all irrelevant code).

The LinkButton is also created **before** the DataBind takes place.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim application As IApplication

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        application = Session("App")             

        If application IsNot Nothing Then

            AddLinkButton("Test", "EntityPage", CommandType.PageLink)
            ShowData(application)                    

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub AddLinkButton(label As String, commandArgument As String,
                         Optional command As CommandType = CommandType.Link)

    Dim linkBtn As New LinkButton()        
    linkBtn.Text = label
    linkBtn.CssClass = "myLinkBtn"
    linkBtn.CommandName = command.ToString
    linkBtn.CommandArgument = commandArgument

    AddHandler linkBtn.Click, AddressOf LinkButton_Click

    panel.Controls.Add(linkBtn)
End Sub


Private Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim linkBtn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)

    Select linkBtn.CommandName

        Case "Link" :

            Response.Redirect(linkBtn.CommandArgument, False)

        ' more cases + additional logic that I removed from the example

    End Select

End Sub

Friend Sub ShowData(application As IApplication)

    Dim entities As List(Of Entity)

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        entities = application.GetEntities() 
        myGridView.DataSource = entities
        myGridView.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

Why do you think this is happening? And is there any way to possibly interrupt the data bind successfully?

**EDIT:** Also tried using Button instead of LinkButton, and using `UseSubmitBehavior = True`, but same result.

Comment: If you want to create a link, just create a link(!) (a-tag) and don't use linkbutton. Linkbutton will cause a postback to happen, link-tag will not. The postback is not needed here since you just want the user to follow a link to another page. Postback will post the whole page back to the server to be parsed, which is time consuming/inefficient and not needed here.

Comment: @Esko can this be done while also allowing me to run the "LinkButton_Click" event handler?

Comment: I'm afraid not, in your example you are not doing anything else than redirecting, what needs to be done before that?

Comment: @Esko I removed some code in LinkButton_Click. There is usually a lot more select-case statements and additional logic, so it is needed.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the link won't be enough. You could do the logic with javascript/ajax, or change the logic othervice. But seems like this is all a bandage for the real problem which is too large databinding. Wouldn't paging/filterin the data make it more user friendly also?

Comment: @Esko I mentioned that paging would be ideal but it needs to be a future feature. Still, I find it unsettling that a user could cause an error if they were impatient. In the meantime, I'll have to try and figure out if I can achieve things a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the wrong track: there is nothing wrong with your data nor its volume. What's wrong is this:

> The LinkButton is also created before the DataBind takes place.

This is simply not enough. You need to create dynamic controls (such as your LinkButton) earlier in the page life cycle, because ASP.NET must do its magic and setup the `ViewState` for the dynamic controls too. Note that creation of the `ViewState` occurs earlier in the lifecycle than the `Load` event. [As stated on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the `PreInit` event is the right place to *create or re-create dynamic controls*. So you gonna need to get rid of the `AddLinkButon` sub and add the following within your code behind file:

```
Private linkBtn As LinkButton ' Declare the LinkButton variable at a module level

Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    linkBtn = New LinkButton()        
    linkBtn.Text = "Test"
    linkBtn.CssClass = "myLinkBtn"
    linkBtn.CommandName = CommandType.PageLink.ToString
    linkBtn.CommandArgument = "EntityPage"

    AddHandler linkBtn.Click, AddressOf LinkButton_Click
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    ' During Init all the controls have been created.
    ' During the PreInit event the "panel" control is unavailable.
    panel.Controls.Add(linkBtn)
End Sub
```

And modify the load handler:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim application As IApplication

    If Not IsPostBack Then    
        application = Session("App")             
        linkBtn.Visible = application IsNot Nothing

        If linkBtn.Visible Then
            ' Remove that next line
            ' AddLinkButton("Test", "EntityPage", CommandType.PageLink)
            ShowData(application)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just got back to work today so sorry for the delayed reply. That you very much! Worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is not because of large amount of data in GridView. This will Validates PostBack is from correct path/source which will be gone by setting `EnableEventValidation="false"` in your page.

---

As you won't set `EnableEventValidation="false"` then you can do something like this:

- Place your GridView inside an UpdatePanel control and do `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` trigger for your GridView.

  ```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 

  <ContentTemplate> 
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
       </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate> 
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="GridView1" />
  </Triggers>

  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  ```
- In your GridView add `RowCommand` event and place your LinkButton/Button code there, by checking correct `e.CommandName == "LinkButtonCommandName"` and find your GridViewRow for other working.

  ```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
      Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
      Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index) // find GridView clicked row
      // find LinkButton from GridView row
      Dim LinkButton1 As LinkButton = CType(GridViewRow.FindControl("LinkButton1"), LinkButton)
      //... here some logic
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It didn't solve the problem but it was worth a shot. Because of the amount of data, the GridView is constantly rendering the data as I try to leave the page which is why I thought the grid was the problem.

Comment: you can handle LinkButton as in RowCommand which will saves you from this error.

Comment: I tried but "RowCommand" does not fire when the button is pressed. The LinkButton is not inside the GridView and any redirect caused by clicking on any link on the page will trigger this.

Comment: I have edited and you can find your LinkButton from `GridViewRow`

Comment: I mean, the LinkButton should not be inside the GridView as I am using the LinkButton for page navigation at the top of the web page. Any link on the entire page also causes this issue, even images with hyperlinks on them. If you interrupt the DataBind then this error occurs.

Comment: Setting `EnableEventValidation = False` is strongly inadvisable! It widens the attack surface and MUST not be used in production environments.

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev so you have to use UpdatePanel for alternative.

Comment: @Asif.Ali No. While it's useful for enhancing page performance and the UX, it's not a solution to the current problem at all, since event validation is performed at callbacks too. See my answer.